# How to search the 2nd form in this html with selector-syntax

Tags: jsoup

With the given HTML-Code

```
<code>&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
   &lt;form&gt; 
      &lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;
   &lt;/form&gt;
   &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt; 
   &lt;form&gt; 
      &lt;p&gt;test2&lt;/p&gt; 
   &lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code>
```

I'm not able to search for the 2nd form-Tag with this selector-syntax:

```
Elements result = doc.select("form:eq(1)");
```

I just get nothing back. If I remove the script-tag from source the select works as expected and I get back the test2-paragraph.
Why does eq(1) not work as expected here?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on jsoup selectors defines the `:eq(n)` pseudo selector as matching "elements whose sibling index is equal to n". The sibling index is the index of the element amongst the parents children.

In your example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
     <form></form>      <!-- Sibling Index: 0 -->
     <script></script>  <!-- Sibling Index: 1 -->
     <form></form>      <!-- Sibling Index: 2 -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Therefore to get the second form using a selector:

```
doc.select("form:eq(2)");
```

Otherwise the `eq(int)` method does what you expected:

```
doc.select("form").eq(1);
```

The behaviour of the selector is different from jQuery where the`eq(n)` pseudo selector matches the n-th element in the set of previously matched elements.

References:

- [jsoup: Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [jsoup: Node.siblingIndex()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingIndex())
- [jsoup: Element.eq(int)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#eq(int))
- [jQuery: eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)